# Pause a download in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm unsure of what the best approach is for pausing a download. I have seen this question asked on stack over flow before, but doesn't seem to achieve the results I am looking for. For example: I understand inside of the AppDelegate, the - `(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` is called if a phone call comes on the phone for example. It is crucial for my app to successfully download the database to function appropriately. Here's the code I use to download the database:

NSString *urlDb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someURl'];

```
//---Create URL from where DB has to be download-----
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlDb];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
```

Pausing a download may not be critical for example, AT&T, but folks with Verizon cannot talk and download at the same time. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pause/Resume downloads in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170773/pause-resume-downloads-in-objective-c)

Comment: Probably a dupe, but better to use [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to do this today, rather than the way in the dupe question.

Comment: I suggest you also look into [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), an excellent, well supported and widely used networking library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pause/resume functionality, then you must use either old NSURLConnection, and implement all required delegate methods, or you can use new NSURLSession API.
Here is a basic implementation with NSURLConnection:

```
@property NSFileHandle *fileHandle;
@property NSURLConnection *connection;

// start download

- (IBAction)downloadButtonPressed
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myUrl"];
    NSURLRequest *dataRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:dataRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}
```

Implement delegate methods

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    self.fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@“pathToYourFile”];
    [self.fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.fileHandle writeData:data];
}
```

If you want to pause - just cancel connection like this:

```
[self.connection cancel];
```

Then you can resume like this:

```
- (void)resumeDownload
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myUrl"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *dataRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:pathToYourFile error:&attributesError];
    NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    NSString *bytesRangeHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%lld-", [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
    [_request setValue:bytesRangeHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:dataRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}
```